# Hindi UTF-8 font not being displayed in Internet Explorer

Tags: internet-explorer, utf-8, fonts, internationalization, webfonts

I developed a multilingual website http://www.governmentjobsworld.com/en/ . This website currently supports two languages 1. English and 2. Hindi (http://www.governmentjobsworld.com/hi/). I am able to view this websites pages in both the languages in Mozilla Firefox and Chrome. But pages in Hindi are not displaying Hindi characters in Internet Explorer. My IE version is 11. I did some research to support UTF-8 in IE but that did not help. Please let me know what I am missing.

Comment: Note that I have added html tags that people have recommended to solve this problem at various places. <html lang="hi">
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
<meta charset="UTF-8">

Comment: So what *is* displaying in IE11?

Comment: Static Hindi Characters that are coming from html file. But Hindi UTF-8 characters that are coming from database, are not being displayed.

Comment: So it's just another duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/279170/utf-8-all-the-way-through?

Comment: It is not a duplicate of that. I have configured database and web server properly to support multiple languages and that is why my website is being displayed properly in Hindi and English on Firefox and Chrome. This issue is coming only with Hindi on Internet Explorer 11.

Comment: Looks good in IE here. What do you see instead of Hindi?